# How to view the source of a JSP file client side

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have been writing c#, html, js, jquery for awhile and been using F12 in chrome and IE to look at the html code to help me with some dom manipulation. I am curious if there is a way to do something similar to that context to look at a jsp page and manipulate it with javascript.

For example: viewsource on a jsp page and fill out a textbox on the jsp page with javascript.

I hope the question is clear and the example makes sense. I am not working on anything with this so I don't have a real example. This is more of curiosity. I know javascript but I am not familiar with java at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsp file gets compiled to a servlet on the Application Server which is then executed. This servlet then produces html on the server side, therefore you can not view the jsp source code client side (F12 in chrome). You can only view the generated output (html, css, js, ...).

[image]

Source: http://oreilly.com/catalog/jserverpages2/chapter/ch03.html

Comment: thanks for the explanation. That iss helpful. I guess for the generated html output produced by the server, I can view it by F12 but might be limited if the page is written to have some javascript tasks run after the document has been loaded. I recently tested out doing a F12 on a popup from jsp and all i can see was a couple hidden input tags even though the page is showing a login and password textboxes. Thanks again for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

JSP is compiled and run on the server side--the same place you edit it (more or less).

Only HTML is sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

In addition,

You write in C#, so if you generate simple ASP.NET page and see how a dynamic page is being generated.

It's not JSP/Java but It have the same concept of dynamic pages.